# Preserve key order loading YAML from a file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, load, key, yaml

I want to preserve the order of the keys in a YAML file loaded from disk, processed in some way and written back to disk.

Here is a basic example of loading YAML in Ruby (v1.8.7):

```ruby
require 'yaml'

configuration = nil
File.open('configuration.yaml', 'r') do |file|
  configuration = YAML::load(file)
  # at this point configuration is a hash with keys in an undefined order
end

# process configuration in some way

File.open('output.yaml', 'w+') do |file|
  YAML::dump(configuration, file)
end
```

Unfortunately, this will destroy the order of the keys in `configuration.yaml` once the hash is built. I cannot find a way of controlling what data structure is used by `YAML::load()`, e.g. alib's `orderedmap`.

I've had no luck searching the web for a solution.

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Then, there is no way you can do that. Hashes in ruby 1.8 do not have the concept of ordering.

Comment: @sawa: Isn't there a gem that does ordered hashes in Ruby 1.8? (I can't recall if it monkeypatches Hash or creates its own class, though)

Comment: @Andrew I found OrderedHash: https://rubygems.org/gems/orderedhash. I looks like it creates a subclass of Hash, holding the order information as an instance variable array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're stuck using 1.8.7 for whatever reason (like I am), I've resorted to using `active_support/ordered_hash`. I know `activesupport` seems like a big include, but they've refactored it in later versions to where you pretty much only require the part you need in the file and the rest gets left out. Just `gem install activesupport`, and include it as shown below. Also, in your YAML file, be sure to use an !!omap declaration (and an array of Hashes). Example time!

```
# config.yml #

months: !!omap
  - january: enero
  - february: febrero
  - march: marzo
  - april: abril
  - may: mayo
```

Here's what the Ruby behind it looks like.

```
# loader.rb #

require 'yaml'
require 'active_support/ordered_hash'

# Load up the file into a Hash
config = File.open('config.yml','r') { |f| YAML::load f }

# So long as you specified an !!omap, this is actually a
# YAML::PrivateClass, an array of Hashes
puts config['months'].class

# Parse through its value attribute, stick results in an OrderedHash,
# and reassign it to our hash
ordered = ActiveSupport::OrderedHash.new
config['months'].value.each { |m| ordered[m.keys.first] = m.values.first }
config['months'] = ordered
```

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to recursively dig through a `Hash` loaded from a `.yml` file, look for those `YAML::PrivateClass` objects, and convert them into an `ActiveSupport::OrderedHash`. I may post a question on that.

Answer (score 3):

Use Ruby 1.9.x. Previous version of Ruby do not preserve the order of Hash keys, but 1.9 does.

Comment: At the time I was stuck with 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

Someone came up with [the same issue](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/66). There is a gem [ordered hash](https://rubygems.org/gems/orderedhash). Note that it is not a hash, it creates a subclass of hash. You might give it a try, but if you see a problem dealing with YAML, then you should consider upgrading to ruby1.9.