# rails i18n rename key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I work on a project translated to over 20 languages. I need to rename some keys, i.e. 'some.key.with.deep.nesting' to 'this.lives.in.another.place'. How do I do it? Manually moving parts of tree in YAMLs 20 times for each is too long and tedious. Are there some standard practices for managing i18n in Rails?

Official guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) explains how to start with i18n, but says nothing about managing translations.

There are some external solutions like localeapp.com, but last time i tested it, it failed to rename keys.

There are also projects like copycopter, i haven't installed it yet, but in description there's also nothing about renaming keys.

So what do you use to manage, rename, move and reorganize your locales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localeapp allows you to rename keys easily — you just need to press the additional options button:

[image: button]
[image: example]

And it does so for all your locales at once. Perhaps this feature was added after you tried it — it is beta after all.

Comment: No, this feature was there when i tried, it just didn't work :)
Though seems to work now. I'll do some experimenting with other tools and stick with localeapp if they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind your i18n files being mangled you can just use the console to read them in with a yaml parser, move the hashes around and dump it out to files again with a yaml encoder.

Comment: If using Ruby 1.9.x, order can be preserved. You can read [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956473/preserve-key-order-loading-yaml-from-a-file-in-ruby) and the ones linked from there

Comment: That's what i did before, though it's kind of messy. I wish there was more clear way.

Answer (score 1):

For translation management in rails you can give [phraseapp](https://phraseapp.com) a try. It provides an in-place editor as well as key management.

Answer (score 0):

copycopter is just for this.
https://github.com/copycopter/copycopter-server

Here is also a rails cast
http://railscasts.com/episodes/336-copycopter

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I found no way to rename key in copycopter. It would be great if you pointed me to how I can do it.

Comment: @Ineu Just found out that copycopter [is closing](https://copycopter.com/pages/shut-down). So it's not a viable option anyway.

Comment: To be accurately it's not closing but source! You can build a server by yourself.